# Calculate the total values of two card blackjack hands

Tags: c

I need to write a function that takes the values of a two-card blackjack hands as input, and prints out the point total of the hand. This what I have so far, but the total returns 0.

```
int card_score(int num_of_cards)
{


char card_value[SIZE];
int ace_seen=0, total=0;

for (int i=0; i<num_of_cards;i++)

{
    switch (card_value[i])
    {

        case 'a': case 'A':
            total +=11;
            ace_seen++;
            break;
        case 'k': case 'K':
        case 'q': case 'Q':
        case 'j': case 'J':
        case 't': case 'T':
            total +=10;
            break;

        case '9':
            total +=9;
            break;

        case '8':
            total +=8;
            break;

        case '7':
            total +=7;
            break;

        case '6':
            total +=6;
            break;

        case '5':
            total +=5;
            break;

        case '4':
            total +=4;
            break;

        case '3':
            total +=3;
            break;

        case '2':
            total +=2;
            break;

        default:  
            printf("Invalid cards. Please try again.");                         
            break;


    }
}
         return total;

}


int main()
{
    char card_value[SIZE];
    int num_of_cards = 0;
    int total;
    int i = 0;

    printf("\n\nEnter cards: ");
    scanf("%c", &card_value[i]);

    total  = card_score(num_of_cards);
    printf("\n\nYour score is %d: \n",total);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your num_of_cards is 0. It doesnt even enter the loop. Maybe ask the user to input or hardcode it to what you actually want

Comment: ok I did added hardcoded input int card_score(int num_of_cards)
{
    
char card_value[SIZE];
int ace_seen=0, total=0;
    
printf("\n\nEnter number of cards: ");

scanf("%i", &num_of_cards);

    
for (int i=0; i<num_of_cards;i++)
    
{
.. It still comes up as 0

Comment: print num_of_cards after you input the value you want. See if it is actually being stored in num_of_cards.

Comment: card_value[SIZE] cpntains no elements. You initialize it in main but card_score(int num_of_cards) has no way of knowing what you initialized it to

Comment: I added scanf to the for loop, but it only reads and totals first card value               #define SIZE 50


int card_score(int num_of_cards)
{
    
char card_value[SIZE];
int ace_seen=0, total=0;

    
    printf("\n\nEnter number of cards: ");
    
    scanf("%i", &num_of_cards);

    printf("\n\nEnter cards: ");
    
    
    
    
for (int i=0; i<num_of_cards;i++)

{
   
    scanf("%c", &card_value[i]);
    switch (card_value[i])
    {
            
        case 'a': case 'A':
            total +=11;
            ace_seen++;
            break;
        case 'k': case 'K':    ......

Comment: that seems more like your for loop condition is being met. what num_of_cards are you using?

Comment: int main()
{
// char card_value[SIZE];
 int num_of_cards;
    int total;
  //  int i = 0;
    
   
  
 
 total  = card_score(num_of_cards);
    printf("\n\nYour score is %d: \n",total);
    return 0;
}
This is my main function

Comment: This is my terminal output Enter number of cards: 2


Enter cards: A 5


Your score is 11:   //I am using 2 for num_of_cards

Comment: Try using a temp variable to store the card and then placing it in card_value[i]

Comment: printf("\n\nEnter cards: ");
    scanf("%s", &temp);
    
for (int i=0; i<num_of_cards;i++)

{
   
   
    card_value[i]=temp;
    
    switch (temp)
    {
            
Now I got weird total 22 for all the inputs

Comment: Basically the first card value that has been entered multiplies itself by 2

Comment: for (int i=0; i<num_of_cards;i++)

{
   
    scanf("%s", &card_value[i]);
    temp=card_value[i];
    
    switch (temp)
    {

Answer (score 1):

You never set the value of `num_of_cards` to anything other than zero, which you set while declaring it. Therefore, you call your `card_score` function with `0` cards, and your `for` loop never runs.

```
for (int i=0; i<num_of_cards;i++)  // i is never < num_of_cards
```